# How to get HTML value from XElement?

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

The XML file that I am trying to parse has an element that may contain HTML. I try to get the value like this:

```
data.Description = root.Element(namespace+ "Description").Value;
```

But when the value is HTML, I get back the plain text representation of the HTML. Is there any way to get the original value of XElement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `.ToString()`, which returns the outer XML source (including the tag itself)

Comment: Not ideal but good enough for sure. Thanks. I hope to see InnerXmlSource method some day...